# Start a HTML5 video after a certain amount has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Can you tell me how to start a HTML5 video after it loaded a certain amount?  For example if i have a 10 second video and i want it to start only when it loaded at least 5 seconds. How can i determine when that happenes?

**Edit**: We assume that the video is loading and it is in a `.pause()` position not in `.stop()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the `buffered` property of the video element to see what time ranges have been loaded. The `buffered` property is a collection of time ranges that have been loaded; you can read the start and end of the `n`<sup>th</sup> range with `buffered.start(n)` and `buffered.end(n)`. Since you're interested in the end-time of the first range, you can read the number of seconds loaded on some video `videoElm` with `videoElm.buffered.end(0)`.

A `<video>` element fires `progress` events to indicate that it has loaded a new chunk of data (and consequently that the end time of some time range in `buffered` is increasing).

You can check if your loaded buffer is big enough after each `progress` event:

```
var someVideo = document.getElementById("myVideoId");

someVideo.addEventListener("progress", function playOnLoad(e) {
    var theVideo = e.target;
    if(theVideo.buffered.length > 0 &&    // if we have a buffer
       theVideo.buffered.end(0) >= 5) {   // if first buffer is at least 5 secs
        theVideo.play();
        theVideo.removeEventListener(playOnLoad);
    }
});
```

If you're actually interested in whether the video can safely play through without interruption, the browser uses the [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough) event. The browser will fire this event when it predicts that the loading rate of the video will allow it to play through without interruption (but it may sometimes be wrong, if the loading rate suddenly changes).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible since every browser has it's own measurement in seconds when a video is ready to be played e.g. the browser controls the buffer load.

The `preload` attribute on the video element gives you some form of control, but not in seconds and not cross-browser consistent.

Check the table on this [page](http://www.browserscope.org/user/tests/table/agt1YS1wcm9maWxlcnINCxIEVGVzdBioyaYUDA?v=1&layout=simple).

I'm not sure why you would control this. The only thing you should be worried about is if the video can play through.

```
this.video.on('canplaythrough', function () {
    this.video[0].play();
}.bind(this));
```

If for some reason you need to capture an event earlier check this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp) for other events.